# 無線LANの屋外利用について

Tags: network, wifi

無線LANで「5Ghz帯は屋外使用不可」とありますが、定義がよくわからないのでご質問です。

自宅の敷地内で隣の離れの室内にWi-Fi中継器を設置して電波を繋げたいのですが、そういうのも屋外利用になるのでしょうか？

それとも、中継器などを外に置くことだけが屋外利用となるのでしょうか。
ご回答をよろしくお願いします。

Answer (score 5):

法律(電波法)で定められたルールによる制限です。

> 5GHz帯を使用する場合、5.2GHz、5.3GHz帯域の電波の屋外での使用は電波法により禁じられています。

5GHz帯にもいくつか種類があり、**屋外**向けの帯域もあるようですが、**屋内**の定義は以下になるようです。

> 屋内とは四方が壁に囲われた建造物の内部の空間をいい、駅のホームや自動車や電車など乗り物の中は屋外の扱いとなります

参考：
[5GHz帯で利用する | Aterm ユーザーズマニュアル](http://www.aterm.jp/function/mr04ln/guide/5ghz.html)
[無線LANの5.2GHz帯（W52）、屋外利用を可能に、電波法施行規則を改正へ](https://internet.watch.impress.co.jp/docs/news/1122349.html)

Comment: 一応10ｍ程度しか離れていない家屋なので用途的には５ｇでも大丈夫です。（今あるwifiでも弱いながら電波は届いてました。）2.4ghzで試したところ問題はないので自分だけならそれでいいのですが、そういう切り替えができない人がいるので・・・。

Comment: cubickさんのAtermユーザーズマニュアルを見ると物を屋内で使うならば大丈夫そうですね。その電波を家と家の間の屋外で使うのはだめそうですね。ありがとうございます。

Comment: 気象レーダーと干渉するためです。特に、お近くの場合はご自身の無線LANが定期的に切れてしまい、悪い影響の方が大きいでしょう。

Comment: ザル法なんですけどね...ｗ 守るに越したことは無いです。

Comment: 一応総務省へ電話して確認したらやはり５ｇｈｚはガレージなどへの使用は不可との回答でした。2.4でも動画見るレベルのことはできるのでそちらのみ使用するようにします。ありがとうございました。

Answer (score 1):

面白かったので、ググってみました。どうやら、法律で規制されているんですね。
へーと
http://kaden-r-han.blog.jp/archives/5GHz.html

法解釈の問題はいくらでもあるのですが、お使いのwifi中継器が5Ghz帯で屋外に設置されていればNGなのではないでしょうか？また、5Ghz帯は2.4Ghz帯に遮蔽物に弱く
お使いの用途にはあわないのでは？と考えます。いずれにしても、厳密な法解釈は弁護士など専門のかたに相談されるのがよいかと思います。ここはエンジニアは多いですが、法律関係が専門の方はすくないと思うので。。。